# Cannot Call Value of Non-Function Type 'UICollectionView' in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

**Intended Outcome**

A generic private method for creating tabbbar icons in a custom tabbar controller. Should successfully paint the tabbar icons for each indicated controller.

**Result**

Fails with

> Cannot Call Value of Non-Function Type 'UICollectionView'

**Failing (Generic) Code:**

```
private func createNavController(imageName: String, _ controllerName: UICollectionViewController) -> UINavigationController {

               let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
Thrown Here->  let viewController = controllerName(collectionViewLayout: layout)
               let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
               navController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

               return navController


       }
```

**Working (non-generic) Code**

```
 let userLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let userController = UserController(collectionViewLayout: userLayout)
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userController)
navController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "loc-map-route")
```

**Related**

```
class UserController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    }
}
```

**Environment**

> ios 10 swift 3 xcode 8

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition of `createNavController` your parameter `controllerName` is of type `UICollectionViewController` and that is not a function type so you cannot call it as a function, i.e. `controllerName(...)`.

If you replace

```
let viewController = controllerName(collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

with

```
let viewController = UserController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

from your working code, it compiles fine. Also, you don't need the `controllerName` parameter anymore. I don't quite understand what this is for anyway. Did you want to be able to specify the controller *type*? Then you could do it like dan suggests (although this code requires a `UICollectionViewController` because you would be using `init(collectionViewLayout:)`).

You could also pass an instance of the view controller you want embedded in the navigation controller like this:

```
private func createNavController(imageName: String, rootViewController: UIViewController) -> UINavigationController
{
           let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
           navController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
           return navController
}
```

and call it like this:

```
let navController = createNavController(
    imageName: "loc-map-route",
    rootViewController: UserController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
```

This would indeed not require a `UICollectionViewController` because `UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:)` takes a `UIViewController`. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
private func createNavController<T: UICollectionViewController>(imageName: String, _ controllerName: T.Type) -> UINavigationController {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let viewController = controllerName.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    navController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    return navController
}
```

Then you can do: `let nav = createNavController(imageName: "loc-map-route", UserCollectionController.self)` and nav will have a `UserCollectionController` as its root.

Answer (score 0):

I think that controllerName is an instance of UICollectionViewController, so it is an already initialized UICollectionViewController. It is not the name of the UICollectionViewController subclass. So if you just want to set the collectionViewLayout of that UICollectionViewController, I'd do:

```
private func createNavController(imageName: String, _ controllerName: UICollectionViewController) -> UINavigationController
{
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let viewController = controllerName.collectionViewLayout = layout
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    navController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    return navController
}
```

The you would call it like this:

```
let navController = createNavController(imageName: "my_image", myCreatedUserController)
```

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. How do you you call the method?

Comment: Although dan's answer is more generic, you might want to try his answer out.